# Is there a standard analogous to the iCalendar RRULE for events that are dependent on the last (possibly late) completion time?

Tags: icalendar, schedule, rrule

I'm looking at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5 and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7529#section-4.1 , and I think this forms a great standard for generating a static set of timestamps for calendar events.

To explain my question better, I would like to start with an example.

```
FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2
```

This will start with a provided DTSTART, and the event will recur every second day after that point. Similarly

```
FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2;BYHOUR=10;BYMINUTE=30;BYSECOND=0
```

will ensure that these recurrences will occur at 10:30 every second day.

However, I think there is also a concept, where we are not scheduling events, but tasks. If a task is completed late, the sometimes, we do not want the task to be performed again at some statically scheduled time, but rather, the next time should be dependent on the last completion time.

If we're happy with a recurrence frequency, then it is simple to calculate the next time the task is due, with

```
lastCompletionTime + frequency
```

where lastCompletionTime is some timestamp object, and frequency represents a duration.

To give a concrete example, if we have a frequency of 1 hour:

```
currentDueTime: 2021-07-23T07:00:00.000+10:00
lastCompletionTime: 2021-07-23T07:30:00.000+10:00 // so, this has been completed late
newDueTime: 2021-07-23T08:30:00.000+10:00
```

However, let's come back to the example where our frequency is two days. Here's an example of what I would like to happen.

```
currentDueTime: 2021-07-23T10:30:00.000+10:00
lastCompletionTime: 2021-07-24T15:00:00.000+10:00 // this has been completed late, over a day after it was due
newDueTime: 2021-07-26T10:30:00.000+10:00 // now due two days after completion, but, at 10:00, so this is not calculated just by adding a 48 hour frequency
```

This leads me to think it would be nice to be able to use RRULEs to define a set of timestamps which cannot be known ahead of time. Or, a set could be generated ahead of time, assuming all future completions occur at the due time.

Another feature that would be useful, would be the ability to constrain the recurrences. For example, I might want an activity to be due every 40 minutes (after each lastCompletionTime), but, only between 09:00 and 17:00, every weekday. A lastCompletionTime close to 17:00 should produce a newDueTime at 09:00 on the next day, in this example.

The question is, is there a standard that extends the RRULE concept somewhere that I am missing, or an analogous standard for generating timestamps in this way? Even better, is there an implementation somewhere?

Comment: About 5 minutes after I posted this, it occurred to me that a hacky implementation might take an existing RRULE library, and set DTSTART=lastCompletionTime, before calculating the next due time. A standard would still be nice though.

Comment: Although, this approach would not cover the concept of constraints. More would would need to be done. Perhaps having further RRULEs to define the start and end times of the constraint periods?